# How to label a violin plot on Seaborn?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, data-science, violin-plot

I'm trying to change the labels in a violin plot on Seaborn. I wanna change the NU_NOTA_CN, NU_NOTA_CH, NU_NOTA_LC, NU_NOTA_MT and NU_NOTA_REDAÇÃO, and TP_ESCOLA, and the 2 and 3.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

fig_dims = (10, 8)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_dims)
sns.boxplot(x="DISCIPLINA", y="NOTA", hue="TP_ESCOLA", data=publica_privada_pivot)  
plt.show()

plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[violin plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StNLX.png)

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: `publica_privada_pivot` isn't defined in your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `set_xticklabels`

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(x="DISCIPLINA", y="NOTA", hue="TP_ESCOLA", data=publica_privada_pivot, ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels([...]) # list of strings
```

In addition, you can use `get_xticklabels`, for example.

```
xticklabels = [t.get_text() for t in ax.get_xticklabels()]
xticklabels = [t.replace('NU_', '').replace('_', ' ').title()
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
foo = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
plt.xticks([0, 1, 2, 3], ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'])
plt.show()
```

The number of unique values in 'day' column (i.e. cardinality of the feature) should be the length of the lists passed to plt.xticks() function.

[matplotlib.pyplot.xticks](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html?highlight=xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks)